# How to prevent Datetimepicker dropdown calendar showing dates greater than max date

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

Required MAX DATE is current date. And requirement is user should be able to enter dates using keyboard and should validate this at the end.

So that now i can enter date which is greater than current date using keyboard. And I am validating entered date on DateTimePicker1_Leave event.  If the entered date is greater than current date it resets value to current date. But when i enter date which is greater than current date and open calendar, it shows dates greater than current date in calendar. I dont want that. It should prevent showing dates which are greater than todays date. I have set MAX DATE as current date on dropdown event. And also used Update(). But still it is showing dates.

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.DropDown
    DateTimePicker1.MaxDate =Now
    DateTimePicker1.Update()
End Sub.
```

Comment: hmmm. It changes just fine for me - can you post the sub where you change the date please? It might me worth adding `DateTimePicker1.Update` (change the name accordingly) just after you change the `MaxDate` property. If this doesn't work, could you still edit your question to include the relevant sub please?

Comment: I have tried using update but it is not working. Also i have put my code in the question. Will u plz help? Many thanks.

Comment: Odd. It works just fine for me - although i did notice that that when attempting to change the year by typing in the year, say I type in the number 2 and then open the picker, it is showing the year as 2002, but  when I scroll to the same date as maxdate, the limit is in place just fine.

Comment: The problem here is if i change the year by typing greater than current year say 2026 then it opens calendar for 2026. It should not happen.

Comment: Really odd. I dont get that behaviour at all. Sorry.

Comment: ahh. now i do. I was still handling the keydown event, not the dropdown. It works fine when using the keydown event - can you use that instead or do you have to use the dropdown event?

Comment: Current date is '09/07/2016'. But if i wantend to select '19/07/2007' it was not allowing me to enter 19 in the date field as MAX DATE is set as current date. So i have used keydown event to set MAX DATE as 31/12/9998. So that i can type any date in the dropdown e.g. 19/07/2016. I am validating this date in the DateTimePicker_Leave event. And it will reset to current date on leaving control. The only problem i m facing is changing date greater than current date and opening calendar.

Comment: I see your problem. I have to go out in a few minutes. I can carry on looking at it later on today.  I should be back home in about 5 hours.  Sorry.

Comment: many thanks for your help,

Comment: Setting the MaxDate property in the DropDown event is too late.  You must set it earlier so an invalid date cannot be selected at all.  The form's constructor is the proper place.

Comment: At the moment, I only have three ideas. One would be to set the maxdate to the end of the month and validate it afterwards to either accept the final value or pop up a message box if the chosen date is after your actual latest date. Another would be to do similar to the above, but use an `ErrorProvider` to have a red exclamation mark next to the picker while the date is out of range and to disable any buttons to move on to the next stage while there is an error.

Comment: The final idea would be to set the default value of the picker to 1 month before the last allowable date, but this would be a pain when the default date falls back to the previous year if the last allowable date is in january. I'd be inclined to go with the error provider.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the op's problem is that if maxdate is set to say 15th July 2016, and the default date is in the same month, they are unable to start typing a date where the day is is after the 15th even though the month that they will type is before July 2016 because as soon as they have typed 16 for the day, the picker thinks that the picker value is 16 July 2016 and is invalid, and then, the picker then corrects the date to the maxdate value.

Comment: Thanks David. I have modified the code in key down event such as now user cant type year greater than current year. But still there is problem with month and day. e.g. if i type 31/08/2016 then it will show august calendar. it should not happen.  Can i use any other event which will verify that i have typed all 3 values i.e. day, month and year and then only validate the final date.

Comment: Sorry - not been near the pc for too long. I've been looking at the datetimepicker behaviour, and imho, it's bugged. It's possible to change the date without the validating event firing. So sadly I suspect that you might have to validate the date on a button click, but I don't know how your program is written. Do you have a button to move on to the next stage when all the data on that form is entered?? If so you could write a sub that checks that the date is in range and call it from within the button click event. If it isn't, exit the button click sub.